# "Just" meaning 'simply' and as a expression of time

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adverbs

Can the adverb 'just' have those two meanings **at the same time** in **past tenses**?

Example:

-I just made this for you. (Can it either mean "simply did" or "recently did"?)

Comment: Yes it can, and the context will resolve any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be specific about the sense of "just" consider three examples that might apply:

"I just made this birthday cake for you this morning." This obviously places the event in the recent past because of the reference to "this morning." The "just" modifies the verb "made."

"I made this birthday cake just for you." This means that I made the cake for you specifically and not for another person. The "just" modifies "for you."

"I just made this birthday cake for you." Depending on context, this could mean something like, "It was no trouble for me to make this cake for you." The sense of "just" is an approximate synonym for "simply."